# Prevent MS Web Development Server (Cassini) from running HttpModules for static content requests

Tags: configuration, web-config, cassini

IIS7 supports this by using `<system.webServer>` configuration element to set module's `preCondition="managedHandler"` attribute.

Since Cassini is a managed server it serves requests in a similar way as IIS7 does. All requests are handled by managed code. By *similar* I mean it executes HttpModules for every single request even if it's static content (scripts, style sheets, images etc.).

It also appears that Cassini ignores `<system.webServer>` configuration settings.

**Q**: Is it possible to either force Cassini not to execute complete pipeline for static content or to obey `<system.webServer>` settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it's not. Which is why testing against IIS is always a good idea :)

Comment: What about UltiDev's solution? Do you know how that one works?

Comment: I mean UltiDev Cassini (http://ultidev.com/products/Cassini/) server that's an upgrated MS Cassini version.